# Hide user form on non active workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a user form that when a workbook is opened, will show a user form with command buttons. I want to be able to open another workbook and not see that userform on the other workbook. I only want to see the user form when that workbook that has the userform is selected and active. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you perhaps add some images to illustrate what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code into your worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    <your code here> 'userform1.show
End Sub
```

Which will run each time you activate that worksheet