# Show userform on worksheet select

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have three worksheets in a workbook. I want to show a specific user form when the user selects one of the worksheets. How can I achieve this in VBA?

Comment: I have looked at your recent posts. You make no effort whatsoever to explain your problem in any detail and show us no evidence that you have tried anything yourself. Please stop posting duplicates and vague questions. We are willing to help you if you show us what you've got so far and add some detail.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to retrieve the current user name. If you want to retrieve the OS user then this is the best solution:

```
Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, lpnSize As Long) As Long

Public Function GetOSUser() As String
    Dim lpBuffer As String * 25

    GetUserName lpBuffer, 25
    GetOSUser = Left(lpBuffer, InStr(lpBuffer, vbNullChar) - 1)
End Function
```

Based on the return value of `GetOSUser()` you can then select the user form to display to the user.

Comment: I get the impression its a different userform based on the selected sheet, rather than the user - It's extremely ambiguous but this is almost a duplicate of a previous question : http://superuser.com/questions/1073210/hide-user-form-on-non-active-workbook